# Blank terminal screen unable to type anything in Platformio-ide-terminal in Atom

Tags: python, terminal, atom-editor, platformio

I have installed platformio-ide-terminal in Atom for working on python project. But when I open the terminal it shows blank screen with no option to write anything.

[Blank terminal screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H3Ar.png)

Can anyone please help me out with this. I have also tried terminal plus and still the same issue.

Comment: I get the same screen as you when I toggle platformio-ide-terminal. Usually, I can hit the return key a couple of times and the window starts responding.

Comment: But that didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

**Below worked for me :**
Open 'Atom' -> 'File' -> 'Settings' -> 'Packages' -> 'Settings' for platformio-ide-terminal -> Scroll down to 'Shell override' and pass correct path of command prompt.

e.g.,
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Here the same problem after the last "platformio terminal' update, the terminal is completely blocked. I opened an case for this on github and found out that the plugin is NO longer supported on Atom. Uninstalling and installing does not solve the problem.

There Microsoft is the owner of Github now, I decided to switch from "Atom" to "VSCode" and  without any regrets till now. (much faster, more stable, same amount of plugins). My terminal works like a charm again!

Comment: That is not a solution but an alternative.